# Installing a window unit in a metal window frame with two raised lips

Tags: windows, air-conditioning

I have a window that has a metal frame with two raised lips. All the diagrams in the installation manual show only one raised lip. The problem is that the bottom frame of the window unit that is supposed to rest against the lip is thicker than the gap between the two lips.

How can/should I go about installing this window unit.

Comment: A picture would help.

Comment: Picture of the window _and_ the supporting rail of the A/C if possible.

Answer (score 1):

My solution has been to build up the inner windowsill by temporarily affixing a 2x4 on top of it, and use that raised surface to mount the AC. Depending on the window hardware, you may be able to align this so the window can be closed normally when the AC isn't present, avoiding the need to dismount and remount the adaptation.

This could be made more attractive, of course. But an AC in the window usually means aesthetics aren't a primary concern.